# How can I plot in Java using Graphics2d.setPaint() fast for large data set

Tags: java

I have a large set of data I wish to plot on a graph that can range from 10k points to about 20 Million Points. At 10k points the plot happens at an ok speed(within a second), but at 20 Million points the plot seems to take minutes.

I'm using Java for the program and rewriting the code in another language just to improve the graphical plotting speed for one single plot that only occurs at at maximum data set is not in the cards.

Is this speed something I have to live with because a 20 Million point plot inherently will take this long due to the data size or am I missing out on some optimisation flag/method/etc?

My Data is in a 2d Array of 13,000 by 4096 called Data.
This is populated from outside the Plot Function in Main.java

```
//In Plot.java
public class PlotG extends JPanel
{
    double xscale = 0.0;
    double yscale = 0.0;
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintCompnent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHint.Key_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHint.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Scaling
        int sizew = Data.size();
        int sizeh = Data.get(0).size();          
        xscale = (getWidth()*1.0)/(sizew *1.0);
        yscale = (getHeight()*1.0)/(sizeh  *1.0);

        //Set Colour
        g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);

        //Plot
        for(int j=0; j<sizew; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<sizeh; k++)
            {
                if(Data.get(j).get(k) > MinimumValueToPlot) //I only plot points above the constant value MinimumValueToPlot
                {
                    int x = xscale*j;
                    int y = yscale*k;
                    g2.fillOval(x,y,1,1);
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}


private Plot dataPlot = new Plot()

public PlotStuff(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> In)
{
    Data = In;
    InitPLot(getContentPane());
}

private void InitPlot(Container contentPane)
{
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1650, 830));
    pack();

    GraphPanel = new JPanel();
    GraphPanel.setBounds(6,11,1470,750);

    GraphPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createTitleBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2),
                    "Title",
                    TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
                    TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
                    new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18),
                    Color.WHITE));
    getContentPanel().add(GraphPanel);
    GraphPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    dataPlot.setBackGround(Color.BLUE);
    dataPlot.setForeGround(Color.WHITE);
    dataPlot.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1470, 750));
    GraphPanel.add(dataPlot);
    return;
}

//in Main.java
.
.
PlotStuff p = new PlotStuff(Data);
p.redrawGraph();
p.setVisible();
.
.
```

Is there anyway to improve the speed if the number of points above my constant *MinimumValueToPlot* reaches 20 Million and above? Given my maximum possible data set is 13k x 4096 = 53,248,000, it is possible, but the highest experienced number of points above *MinimumValueToPlot* is so far only 20 Million.

Am I doing something wrong in the JPanel declarations? I have seen some discussions say that *setPreferredSize* shouldn't be used? Is this the case?

Thanks.

Comment: What is slow about it? If you paint to a BufferedImage off of the EDT and draw the buffered image to your panel your application should stay responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You claim `Data` is a 2d array, but it is not. It is an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`. Work with an actual array instead.

Instead of `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` you'd do `double[][]`.

2. In your loop you are calling `fillOval` to set the color of a single pixel. That causes huge unneccessary overhead. You are basically telling your application to calculate the pixels for an oval shape of size 1x1 20 million times!

I suggest you create a BufferedImage, get its pixel array, and set the pixel values directly. Then, when done, draw that image to your Graphics2d object:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
Graphics2D imgGraphics2D = img.createGraphics();
imgGraphics2D.setColor(Color.white);
imgGraphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
imgGraphics2D.dispose();

byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
for(int j=0; j < sizew; j++)
{
    for(int k=0; k < sizeh; k++)
    {
        if(data[j][k] > minimumValueToPlot)
        {
            int x = (int)(xscale * j);
            int y = (int)(yscale * k);
            int pixelindex = (y * getWidth() + x) * 3;
            pixels[pixelindex + 1] = 255; // set the green byte
        }
    }
}

g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
```

Please take this with a grain of salt, as I wrote this from memory.

*(Also I took the liberty of renaming `Data` to `data` and `MinimumValueToPlot` to `minimumValueToPlot`. Per convention variables in Java start with a lower case letter to distinguish them from classes.)*

Comment: Thanks. I now know that making a BufferedImage is so much faster that a trying to plot point by point using my method. I think the x and y should be switch in the pixelindex calculation, beyond that, my plots now are now loads faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plotting points like that in your paint components means that you paint that many points *every time the component is repainted* This means it is an expensive operation to resize the window, or click a button because it has to repaint every point.

In this version, I've made a method to redo the graphics, and and the paintComponent just repaints the backing buffer. Note, that painting to the backing buffer will be about as fast as you can accomplish paint, and it ignores the display properties of swing. That way you can use a profiler and see how fast you can make the painting routine go. For example using some of the suggestions of Max above.

```
public class PlotG extends JPanel
{
    BufferedImage buffer;
    double xscale = 0.0;
    double yscale = 0.0;

    public PlotG(){
        buffer = new BufferedImage(1470, 750, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintCompnent(g);
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
    }

    void updateBuffer(){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)backing.getGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHint.Key_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHint.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Scaling
        int sizew = Data.size();
        int sizeh = Data.get(0).size();          
        xscale = (getWidth()*1.0)/(sizew *1.0);
        yscale = (getHeight()*1.0)/(sizeh  *1.0);

        //Set Colour
        g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);

        //Plot
        for(int j=0; j<sizew; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<sizeh; k++)
            {
                if(Data.get(j).get(k) > MinimumValueToPlot) //I only plot points above the constant value MinimumValueToPlot
                {
                    int x = xscale*j;
                    int y = yscale*k;
                    g2.fillOval(x,y,1,1);
                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(buffer.getWidth(this), buffer.getHeight(this));
    }
}
```

The problem with setPreferredSize, is not a performance issue, it can conflict with swings swings layout managers. When you have a component, such as your custom graphing panel, you do want to have it determine the size. I've added it to the PlotG class, so now it will try to layout according to the backing buffer.

The you have to update the buffer, I suggest doing it on the main thread after you've set your panel to visible. That way it won't block the edt.